# Нужна ли запятая перед «и»? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

**Пара дней, и очередная дорогая покупка отправляется в чулан или на балкон.**

Подскажите, нужна ли запятая перед "и" в предложении?

Answer (score 2):

**Пара дней — и очередная дорогая покупка отправляется в чулан или на балкон.**

На месте указанной (необходимой) запятой я бы поставила тире.
Контекст отсутствует, но смысл понять несложно. Сначала безоглядно что-то покупаем, а потом всю эту дорогущую и, как оказалось, ненужную красоту складываем, копим, размещаем.

Отсутствует сказуемое в первой части сложносочинённого предложения (например, проходит/пройдет/минует), есть быстрая смена событий, поэтому вместо запятой прямо просится тире.

[Все случаи постановки тире](http://rus.1sep.ru/article.php?ID=200202402)

*«Пара дней, — думал Федор Иванович, не сводя глаз с двух фигур впереди. — Пара дней — и все станет ясно...»* (К. Смородин)

Comment: _Римма Михайлова: В первой части **бессоюзного** предложения и сказуемое отсутствует..._ === Бессоюзного ли?

Comment: Конечно, "обсоюзенное"! Спасибо, поправлю.

Answer (score 0):

Неоднозначный вопрос. Начну с того, что никакого дефиса там быть не может в принципе. Подобные конструкции, кстати говоря, даже в английском есть, но сейчас не об этом.

Если считать, что числительное "два" выступает в роли сказуемого, то запятая нужна на основании соединения двух грамматических основ. Можно также считать, что "два" - определение. В этом случае первое предложение становится назывным, но причина обособления та же. Хотел бы отметить, что это характерно только для несогласованных определений.

Также можно построить предложение по-другому. Если фрагмент взят, например, из дневника, то стоит сочетание "день два" отделить точкой.

*Поправка из-за изменения вопроса*: смотрите только вторую часть ответа (второй абзац).